# Tabs Title not showing

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm facing an issue using the `TabLayout`. I updated the design library to v25.0.0 and now the tab titles are not showing up. Here is my code:

```
public void setupTabs() {
    animateUserProfileOptions();
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
}

public void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
    TabPagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Fragment news = new NotificationNews();
    Fragment request = new NotificationRequests();

    adapter.addFragment(news , getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notification_news));
    adapter.addFragment(request, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.notification_request));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tlUserProfileTabs.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tlUserProfileTabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

Here is my xml layout 
  `enter code here`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/home_primary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlUserProfileTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#28A9E0"
        app:tabTextColor="#999999"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#28A9E0"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

Am I missing something or what? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should not be using `getApplicationContext`. You should use the `Activity` as a `Context`. And why are you creating a `Runnable` to setup the `TabLayout`?

Comment: yes im adding a runnable i posted in the code @Bryan

Comment: *Why* are you adding a `Runnable`? There is no reason to.

Comment: well i checked posts on stack it seems i should plus i tried without it same issue @Bryan

Comment: Is the `setupViewPager()` method in an `Activity`? If not, where is it?

Comment: its in the activity look @Bryan everything was working fine same code but when i updated my support design the tab title are not showing anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127127/discussion-between-bryan-and-mostafa-addam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the **tabTextAppearance**

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@drawable/tab_selector"
```

It might be conflicting with the app selected text color and text color

Answer (score 1):

The `TabPagerAdapter` should look more like this:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final ArrayMap<CharSequence, Fragment> mData = new ArrayMap<>();

    private TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager {
        super(manager);
    }

    public void addFragment(CharSequence title, Fragment fragment) {
        mData.put(title, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mData.valueAt(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mData.valueAt(position);
    }

}
```

And the setup should look more like this:

```
public void setupViewPager() {
    TabPagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.notification_news, new NotificationNews());
    adapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.notification_request, new NotificationRequest());

    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

Comment: i tried it nothing changed your code simplifies mine nothing more @Bryan

Comment: @MostafaAddam Then it could be something with your layout, or possibly the code in your `Activity`. Did you customize the style of your `TabLayout` at all? Could you post the `Activity` code and your XML?

Comment: @MostafaAddam Could the titles be getting cut off? Try setting the `layout_height` of your `TabLayout` to `wrap_content`. Also, try removing all of your `app:tab...` attributes, just to rule out that one of them are not the cause.

Comment: nothing im confused it was working fine before update @Bryan